# Is the performance price of GWT operations with DOM elements really high?

Tags: javascript, performance, gwt, dom

What I want is to get some understanding of the performance price I pay for DOM operations made by GWT. I want to know which operations are "expensive" and which are not, and how can I measure it. I would like to know how can I profile these operations, or may be its not worth to pay attention to this issues at all.

To be more exact, here is a list of use-cases I have encountered.

1) Use case #1: you have a widget that changes its appearance if some event ocurres. Is there any difference if I would remove old widget and create a new one, or its better to change the style of the existing widget? In other words, how big is the price of creating and inserting a new widget in GWT app? Is there any kind of Garbage Collector for removed DOM elements?

2) Use Case #2: you need to get or save some data from/on server-side. The data can be quite big. Is there any sense to create a special Servlet that will make this operation in a very simplified manner: just accepting or printing some String instead of making RPC call to standart GWT servlet? Is this a good way to raise performance? Your self-written Servlet can be very simple.

3) Use Case #3: you have a widget that is a long list of other widgets. How can you estimate which number of widgets is safe to show for client-side performance? I mean if we would show 5 million chat messages for the past 5 years probably client-side will become slowed down, even if we would load the items part by part, thus limiting the server-side stress.

4) Use case #4: what about the performance price of dom operations such as finding out the number of elements inside some container, or finding out style of element? For example, you need to count the number of messages in a chat. Is this operation of counting chat container's DOM children is expensive so much that its better to implement separate counter and increase it as new messages arrive (just like Java Collections do) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Use case #1:` `Updating style is always recommended rather than remove/add widget`. Updating style means CSS parsing/recalculation/painting. Remove/Add widget will lead to DOM & CSS parsing/recalculation/painting.

`Use Case #2:` It really depends on your operation. GWT comes with Three flavors of server side communication. Each of them  are suited for different use cases - read [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication).

```
a) RPC - Remote Procedure calls
b) RF - Request Factory & Entities
c) Request Builder with self-written Servlet serving up Strings,JSON or Autobean.
```

`Use Case #3:` You have [GWT Cell Widgets](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets) to display large data with minimal DOM operations. IF displaying chat message is a requirement give CellList a try with AutoPager on scroll and may be throw in Asynchronous DataProvider.

`Use case #4:` You are supposed to use Java Pojo backed Cell Widgets. Each chat message is a instance of Java Pojo "ChatMessage" and based on your RPC call you fetch a  List and feed it to CellList/CellTable . Why would you count dom when you can count "data" by just a sizeOf of operation on List.

You are thinking way ahead of your project in the wrong direction. DOM operations are a concern if your programming approach is wrong. Go through GWT samples by downloading the [GWT Files](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.0.zip) and execute them by importing to eclipse.

Performance Tuning is the strongest feature of GWT. Given sufficient experience you can tune out any performance issues in GWT using `SpeedTracer, Logging, Chrome Dev tools Profiling, GWT Light Weight Metrics, Code Splitting, GWT Compiler Metrics, GWT Closure Compiler, Resource Bundling and the list goes on....`

Comment: Only note I'd add: RequestBuilder is just the consummate AJAX call, and is used by both RPC and RF, so if the asker wants to make their own message system with essentially raw ajax, go ahead and do it.